# rich:suggestionbox how to call bean in case user aborts selection

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Old SuggestionBox component for RichFaces (version 3.3... yes, I have to maintain legacy code, weep for my fate) is pretty useful, but has one downside.

If user enter some text in input component and then click somewhere else than entry on list of suggestion, partially filled input is left as is. It is ugly and can be confusing, giving impression that something is selected when it is not.

I want to have separate call to bean in this case, allowing me to remove text, if nothing got selected.

Example code:

```
<h:inputText id="selectorInput" value="#{backingBean.inputText}" label="Select something:" />

<rich:suggestionbox id="suggestion" for="selectorInput" suggestionAction="#{backingBean.resolveSuggestions}" var="sug">
    <a4j:support event="onselect" reRender="someForm" action="#{backingBean.select(sug)}" />
    <h:column>#{sug.name}</h:column>
</rich:suggestionbox>
```

I tried to add a4j:support for h:inputText with event="onblur", but it is called **before** backingBean.select(sug) and has no way to know if something was selected or not, making it almost useless. Adding other events to suggestionbox itself appear to not work at all or even break suggestionbox.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The backing JavaScript object has a `getSelectedItems()` method. It returns an empty array if nothing was selected.

To get the object use

```
document.getElementById(clientId).component
```